# How to configure Winlogbeat to connect to AWS elastisearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elk

I would like to send windows events to AWS elastic search. The elasticsearch has api key and security key which is needed to connect. I cant find in winlog beat configuration. please find my yml code below.

```
# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  #hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
   hosts: ["https://vpc-manufacturing-elasticsearch-celm5zj5gcf45hpghulnxshco4.ap-southeast-2.es.amazonaws.com"]
  # Protocol - either `http` (default) or `https`.
  #protocol: "https"

  # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
  #api_key: "id:api_key"
  #username: "elastic"
  #password: "changeme"
    region:"where to specify"
    aws_access_key_id:"where to specify"
    aws_secret_access_key:"where to specify"
  #User: es-mfg
```

Answer (score 1):

Beats don't support AWS Authentication. Your options are:

1. Set up [Fine-Grained Access Control in Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html) and enable basic auth and proceed with elasticsearch output.
2. For IAM-based domain access policy set up [Logstash](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-logstash.html), install [logstash-output-amazon-es plugin](https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es) and properly set your access credentials. Finally, configure logstash output in your beat pointing to this logstash instance.